# Erro ao instalar Compass no Mac

Tags: ruby, terminal, gem, osx

Estou tentando instalar o compass na minha máquina e me deparo com o seguinte erro.

Estou usando com comando com sudo.

```
    Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
    ERROR:  Error installing compass:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby -r      ./siteconf20140930-1189-279ned.rb extconf.rb
    checking for ffi.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
    Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
    libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may need configuration options.

    Provided configuration options:
       --with-opt-dir
       --without-opt-dir
       --with-opt-include
       --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
       --with-opt-lib
       --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
       --with-make-prog
       --without-make-prog
       --srcdir=.
       --curdir
       --ruby=/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby
       --with-ffi_c-dir
       --without-ffi_c-dir
       --with-ffi_c-include
       --without-ffi_c-include=${ffi_c-dir}/include
       --with-ffi_c-lib
       --without-ffi_c-lib=${ffi_c-dir}/
       --with-libffi-config
       --without-libffi-config
       --with-pkg-config
       --without-pkg-config
     /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:434:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
    You have to install development tools first.
    from       /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:549:in `block in try_compile'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:502:in `with_werror'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:549:in `try_compile'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:1044:in `block in have_header'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:895:in `block in checking_for'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:340:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:310:in `open'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:340:in `block in postpone'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:310:in `open'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:336:in `postpone'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:894:in `checking_for'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:1043:in `have_header'
from extconf.rb:16:in `<main>'

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/ffi-1.9.5 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/extensions/universal-darwin-13/2.0.0/ffi-1.9.5/gem_make.out
```

Alguém já teve o mesmo erro? sabe como resolvo?

Answer (score 0):

Aparentemente você não está conseguindo compilar uma extensão em código nativo da *gem*. Ou seja, essa *gem* precisa de algo externo ao ruby que provavelmente foi programado em C.

Recomendo instalar programas para compilar C, como as *developer tools* do *xcode*, e atualizar o seu ruby. Essa resposta tem instruções de como instalar as *developer tools*: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9329325/4068246 [em inglês].

Comment: Então Daniel, já fiz isso de instalar o Developer Tools do Xcode, e tentei por diversas vezes atualizar o ruby. Mais até agora nada disso funcionou.

Comment: @william-costa , Você já tentou usar o RVM para gerenciar a versão do ruby na sua máquina. Uma vez tive problema de não conseguir instalar uma gem que resolveu magicamente quando troquei para o ruby 2.1.2 .

Comment: Não tentei isso ainda Daniel. Vou procurar saber.